# not understanding mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

So i guess i don't understand this i am a very newbie to coding in general. I have searched and can't find a good enogh explanation to get it to work in my situatation. I need to fill a table from a fetch command then update each result with an input of information into a new column. Here is the code i have:

This fills the table:

```
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Envelope</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['envelopename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['envelopebudget'] . "</td>";
    ?><td><input type="text" name="budgetamount"></td><?php;
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>  
    <input type="submit">
```

And this writes the input for budgetname into the column budgetname:

```
$paycheckname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['paycheckname']);
$budgetamount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['budgetamount']);
$envelopename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['envelopename']);
}

$sql="UPDATE envelopes SET $paycheckname='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Right now it just doesn't write anything. I have used echo `var_dump($envelopename)."<br>"; and echo var_dump($budgetamount)."<br>";` to try and see what it is doing but $envelopename is always blank. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You don't have an input for `envelopename`, so there won't be a post value. If `$envelopename` is empty then that is the problem, and it is unrelated to MySQL. Take a smaller stap and first try to build a working static form, just displaying the posted values, before dragging MySQL into your project. This code has a couple of unrelated issues, making it hard to write a good, complete and (re)usable answer for it.

Comment: I think you need to do `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to get an associative array returned as the default is numerical indexes...could be wrong here.

Comment: envelopename is pulled from the database table envelopes which creates the form as shown above. If i can make this simpler please do let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should just go to the PHP documentation and look for mysqli_result::fetch_assoc, that is what you need. To learn more about mysqli_fetch_array: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: I have done that many times but they always explain it with static entries and what i need is pulling variable entries from the table then updating those variable entrees with new information. No explanations on how to do that which is why i asked here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the default type of `mysqli_fetch_array` = `MYSQLI_BOTH` so it will work fine

Comment: @andrew Thanks. been awhile, can't remember everything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only `<input>` , `<textarea>`, `<select>` and `<button>` are submitted to the server in a form

If you want to re-submit some static values create some hidden inputs

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[envelopename]' name='envelopename'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[envelopebudget]' name='envelopebudget'/>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['envelopename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['envelopebudget'] . "</td>";
?><td><input type="text" name="budgetamount"></td><?php;
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

But your next issue will be that you're creating the elements in a loop so you'll have multiple inputs with the same name

```
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' value='envName1' name='envelopename'/>
    <input type='hidden' value='envBudget1' name='envelopename'/>
    <td>envName1</td>
    <td>envBudget1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="budgetamount"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' value='envName2' name='envelopename'/>
    <input type='hidden' value='envBudget2' name='envelopename'/>
    <td>envName2</td>
    <td>envBudget2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="budgetamount"></td>
</tr>
```

so you must submit as an array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[envelopename]' name='envelopename[]'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[envelopebudget]' name='envelopebudget[]'/>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['envelopename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['envelopebudget'] . "</td>";
?><td><input type="text" name="budgetamount[]"></td><?php;
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

and at the server end process as an array

```
 foreach ($_POST['budgetamount'] as $budgetamount){
       echo $budgetamount. '<br>';
  }
```

Comment: This looks like what i need but i want to understand it also. I get the while statement section but in the for each. Does this go under the echo "</table>";  and if so then what would my statements look like to write $budgetamount back to the table? Sorry but i am trying to get this.

Comment: does the form submit to the same page as itself or a different page (is the form action different from the name of the file it is in)? a form can have an action attribute, `<form action="somephpfile.php">` does yours?

Comment: if you answer my question in the above comment, ill post a another answer explaining the foreach loop, but i need to know that first

Comment: I have a seperate action file that the form calls which is newpaycheck.php and my syntax is shown in the second code of my original post. Also do i need to do something different with the echo input statement you gave me cause the page now displays name='envelopename[]'/> name='envelopename[]'/> above my table.

Comment: possible, i did edit the answer and remove a couple of erroneous `>`  so copy it again, preparing you a second answer now

Answer (score 0):

suppose the form rendered looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' value='envName1' name='envelopename[]'/>
    <input type='hidden' value='envBudget1' name='envelopebudget[]'/>
    <td>envName1</td>
    <td>envBudget1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="budgetamount[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' value='envName2' name='envelopename[]'/>
    <input type='hidden' value='envBudget2' name='envelopebudget[]'/>
    <td>envName2</td>
    <td>envBudget2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="budgetamount[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' value='envName3' name='envelopename[]'/>
    <input type='hidden' value='envBudget3' name='envelopebudget[]'/>
    <td>envName3</td>
    <td>envBudget3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="budgetamount[]"></td>
</tr>
```

when the user hits submit the `$_POST` that arrives at `newpaycheck.php` will look like:

```
$_POST
['envelopename']{
   [0]=>'envName1',
   [1]=>'envName2',
   [2]=>'envName3'
},['envelopebudget']{
   [0]=>'envBudget1',
   [1]=>'envBudget2',
   [2]=>'envBudget3'
},['budgetamount']{
   [0]=>'someValueEnteredByUser',
   [1]=>'anotherValueEnteredByUser',
   [2]=>'yetAnotherValueEnteredByUser'
}
```

so you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['envelopename'] as $envelopename){
   $arrayIndex = array_search($envelopename,$_POST['envelopename']);
   $envelopebudget = $_POST['envelopebudget'][$arrayIndex];
   $budgetamount= $_POST['budgetamount'][$arrayIndex];

   $paycheckname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $envelopebudget);
   $budgetamount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$budgetamount);
   $envelopename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$envelopename);

   $sql="UPDATE envelopes SET $paycheckname='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";

   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

}
```

Comment: see ho this goes, sorry i didn't get chance to test it

Comment: Sorry i still have a question. So the foreach statement goes on the form page and if so inside or outside the table or does it go on the action page? I am not good at this but you are very patient. Thank you.

Comment: the foreach loop would go inside `newpaycheck.php` your action page

Comment: This seems to be working except it only uses the last budgetamount input result. You also missed the closing } on the foreach statement but i fixed that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say i missed the `}` ? its right there at the end of the code snippet, the sql statement is inside the foreach loop, it must run  the insert statement for each set of inputs

Comment: sorry you are right but it still just updates the budgetamount for the last envelopename. don't understand.

Comment: see edit, I added the sql insert statement inside the foreach loop, sorry, i wasn't sure if you'd done that I thought  it was implied

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a champ. Good thing this isn't my day job. I will definitely study this and learn what is happening so i don't ask about anything related to this in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: ok the key thing here is the `array_search($envelopename,$_POST['envelopename']);` wrap your head around that and you'll be good to go. ps you can upvote answers as well as accepting, you may even be able to up vote more than one answer from the same user :P

Comment: I am so new to this I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I did try. I will research more on the array_search.